# How to create full world map in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, maps, react-native-maps, world-map

I want to create a full world map where I can plot some points based on provided data.
I have tried many libraries in react native but I am not getting any solutions from it.

This is an image of what I am trying to achieve using react native.
[image: World map with points plotted on it]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

You can create such map using SVGs, by finding a world map SVG and tracking the locations of the countries in this SVG map. Using these locations, you can plot Circles around the countries.

**Prerequisite**

I would suggest reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) to get better understanding of the SVG Path.

### Render the Map

**Step 1**

Download an SVG world map. Things you will need in the svg map image are,

- Each country should be drawn using a separate SVG Path to locate country or nearby region.
- SVG should be scalable.

I downloaded svg map from [SimpleMaps](https://simplemaps.com/resources/svg-world). Here maps have both of the things I mentioned above. You have option to download maps with custom height/width and each country is drawn with separate path.

**Step 2**

Convert the downloaded SVG into JSX, there are many converters available online, [this](https://transform.tools/svg-to-react-native) is the one I use.
Now render this converted JSX on the screen.

With this, we are done with the map.

### Plot The Circles

**Step 1**

While downloading the SVG map, we checked that each country is drawn using separate path, You can also notice that each of this path is having an id or class named after a country. This name may be shorthand. This is how we find path for respective countries.

**Step 2**

To understand this part, it is must to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) first.

Now suppose India's map path starts with `M223.14 53.577`, which means in the whole world map, we will get India's location at this point(223.1, 53.577). In this way you can get location of any country in the map using the path. We can use this point to plot a circle.

**Step 3**

To plot circle on this point, we will use `Circle` from `react-native-svg`,
Draw this circle at the end on the svg, just before closing Svg tag like this,

```
    ...
       <Circle cx={223.14} cy={53.577} r={5} fill={'red'}/>
    </Svg>
```

Note that the location you get from the Path is on border of the country, you may need to tweak the location to get the circle on your desired location.

### Result

I have created [this](https://snack.expo.dev/HbRwfZB6X) snack with free to use map which I downloaded from above suggested site, you may follow it, I have plotted a circle on United kingdom here. As mentioned earlier, you can download map svg in custom dimensions also but I think that is not free to use, so I have not used custom dimension map in it, but you will need a map with custom dimensions to make it fit on mobile screen.

### EDIT

check [this](https://snack.expo.dev/@rohitkhairnar/smelly-milkshake) snack, I have mapped 3 countries in a object and used same api reponse shared by you. It is working DYNAMICALLY also, you now just have to add more countries by there location. I am using [this](https://github.com/VictorCazanave/svg-maps/blob/master/packages/world/world.svg) svg world map here.

I have passed the api response shared by you to the worldmap component

```
<WorldMap apiResponse={apiResponse} />
```

In the `WorldMap` component, I have mapped countries locations to their IDs like this,

```
const COUTRIES = {
  'ZA' : [562.70375, 527.0484],
  'GB' : [471.90475,298.2024],
  'US' : [79.174748,187.7204],
}
```

And to plot circles, I have added Circle at the end of the SVG,

```
    {
      props.apiResponse.map(country => 
        <Circle cx={COUTRIES[country.id][0]} cy={COUTRIES[country.id][1]} r={10} fill={'red'} key={country.id} />
      )
    }
```

Now you just have to update `COUNTRIES` object with each country ID and location,
and it will plot the circles on the map dynamically.

### Screenshot

[image: expected output screenshot]

Comment: How to reduce the size of this world map,that fits in the mobile screen,I downloaded svg image height 857 and width 2000 ,how to reduce that fits in mobile screen.I tried to reduce the size but its not working@Rohit

Comment: also if the data in coming from api to plot this map points,how we can search those points in svg based country name?

Comment: as I mentioned in the answer, you can download SVG map with custom dimesion on that site, which you can easily fit on mobile screen. 
And to plot points on map, you can not search the country location directly, you will have to find country location using id/classname. Then you need to create some data structure to store the locations of the countries by their name.

Comment: I tried many way,but i dont think ,we can search the 200 path components in svg based on className="sm_state sm_state_AT",using my API data like this  [{"id": "US", "name": "UNITED STATES", "value": 3.2}, {"id": "GB", "name": "UNITED KINGDOM", "value": 95.86}, {"id": "ZA", "name": "SOUTH AFRICA", "value": 0.9299999999999999}]

Comment: what issue you are facing while searching for country locations? You can map the country locations as per the country id you are getting from api and plot the circles. If you are looking for some readymade solution, i would suggest trying library mentioned in the other solution but it will not provide control like svg maps.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/VictorCazanave/svg-maps/blob/master/packages/world/world.svg) to another svg map that I found.

Comment: This issue is with searching only ,How we can search and return the cx ,cy values from the <path> components in jsx.Since React Native does not support the ability to search in JSX files directly at runtime, we cannot dynamically access and search the JSX code for a specific Path element based on the className

Comment: we can not search cx, cy for each country, you will have to find these locations for countries first by checking ```path```, and then map countries to these locations.

Comment: yes we cannot search the locations for countries in JSX react native

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254637/discussion-between-manish-kumar-and-rohit-s-k).

Comment: i think this is good for plotting only static data on map,not dynamic data

Comment: @ManishKumar,we can plot data dynamically, please check my updated answer

Comment: thanks @Rohit ,its working but not 100%,for some country its not showing exact location like US ,its not showing at exact path after passing cx and cy values.

Comment: glad it worked, the path gives us location on the border thats why circle is not plotting on exact locations, you will need to tweak the location a little in order to make it center,

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a full map sdk such as mapbox, maplibre, or Google maps and host a custom tileset.

Why use a map sdk?

- Doing all these calculations with an image may work, but it could be time intensive, error prone, require a bunch of testing. VS map-sdk already shipping most of the calculations.
- map specific features. Like showing current location. Map sdks do that well.

Example Mapbox allows for custom map styling and you can host your own tiles/layers directly. [See here](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/styles/)

Most of these services have a react-native variant. Example

- [@rnmapbox/maps](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps)

These services would allow you to use world coordinates to accurately put points on your map. You will need to add a symbol layer for your pins, add the custom images as sources and pin the locations on the map using coordinates matched with the symbol type.

Answer (score 0):

import the map to react native as jpg for better performance and load time speed, then create a pressable, within that pressable create a circle and then create another view and set it's visibility to a hook boolean variable called visible, inside that View create a text tag that will display the data, when the pressable is pressed the useState hook will update the page and set visible to true.

```js
const Car = (props) =>{
 if(props.visibility == true){
 return (<View><Text>Data</Text></View>)
 }
 else{
 return 0;
}

const Map = () => {
const [visible, setvisible] = useState(false);

return(
<Image width={400} height={200} src={require('path')}/>
<Pressable onPress={()=> setvisible(true)}>
<View style={{borderRadius:50,backgroundColor:'red', marginTop: 50, marginLeft:50}}/>
</Pressable>
<Card visibility={visible}/>
);
}
```